# dbix::class modify column data before update or insert

Tags: perl, encryption, catalyst, dbix-class

I am using dbix::class along with catalyst to interact with my database. However, some of the data that I am storing is sensitive so I would like to encrypt in before it goes into the database (is inserted or updated) and decrypt it when it comes out (selected). And I know how by using this module: `DBIx::Class::PassphraseColumn` you can automatically have the password encrypted when putting it into the database by having this in your schema file:

```
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
    '+password' => {
        passphrase       => 'rfc2307',
        passphrase_class => 'BlowfishCrypt',
        passphrase_args  => {
            cost        => 14,
            salt_random => 20,
        },
        passphrase_check_method => 'check_password',
    }
);
```

So that anytime you update a password you don't have to worry about encrypting it, DBIx just does it for you. Would there be a similar way to where whenever I inserted or updated a value into a column it would encrypt it for me and whenever I selected it it would be decrypted for me? Or maybe is there a way to add a method that's called before an insert or an update or after a select that gives you a chance to manipulate the data? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with `DBIx::Class`, but if you can do this for one column, can't you build a loop with all your fields in it and add this for each of them? You could even get the columns first with a `SHOW FIELDS` statement for each table. A bit tedious and I guess that there is a way to add a handler to `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `SELECT`, but it's a start.

Comment: Usually you would add such methods to your `ResultSet` class.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [column accessor overloading](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aManual%3a%3aCookbook#Wrapping-overloading-a-column-accessor). You could encrypt the data in @_ if it wasn't empty, and decrypt whenever you return the value. I've modified the example on that page to better suit your needs:

```
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(description => { accessor => '_description' });

sub description {
    my $self = shift;

    # If there is an update to the column, encrypt it before calling the original accessor
    return $self->_description(encrypt($_[0])) if @_;

    # Fetch and decrypt the column value.
    return decrypt($self->_description);
}
```

You'd still need to specify encrypt() and decrypt(), but this gets you most of the way there.